# StripeInvalidRequestError when cancelling subscription on connected account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to cancel a stripe subscription on a connected account (in test mode), but I am getting the following error:

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: No such subscription: SUBSCRIPTION_ID
```

I can see the subscription with `SUBSCRIPTION_ID` in my Stripe dashboard, and cancel it from there. I've tried the following, with and without the `stripe_account` argument:

```
 stripe.subscriptions.del(
   SUBSCRIPTION_ID, { at_period_end: true }
 ), {
    stripe_account: stripeAccountId
 };
```

I am able to cancel subscriptions on the platform account with no trouble. Do I need to first authenticate with the connected account's API key? Or is there another method I should be using here?

Edit: the subscription is on the account whose id matches `stripeAccountId`

Comment: Is the Subscription in the Stripe Account associated with `stripeAccountId`?  Is there actually a value in `stripeAccountId`?

Comment: there is actually a value, and it matches the account that the subscription is associated with

Comment: The only way you could get this error is if the `SUBSCRIPTION_ID` you're providing doesn't belong to either the `stripeAccountId`, or it does, but `stripeAccountId` is actually `undefined`.  What do you get if you `console.log()` SUBSCRIPTION_ID and `stripeAccountId`?  You might also want to write into Support about this one so they can look into the details for you: https://support.stripe.com/email/login

Comment: both are defined and are the correct values. Viewing the dashboard as the account with id `stripeAccountId`, I can see the subscription with `SUBSCRIPTION_ID` and am able to manually cancel it there. So I'm at a loss here. I will reach out to Stripe support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was a typo.. I had misplaced a closing bracket. Here is the corrected API call

```
stripe.subscriptions.del(SUBSCRIPTION_ID, {
  at_period_end: true
}, {
  stripe_account: stripeAccountId
});
```